# Calculating $\int_{0}^{\pi }{\frac{x\sin \left( x \right)}{a+b{{\cos }^{2}}\left( x \right)}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to find for $a>b>0$ :
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi }{\frac{x\sin \left( x \right)}{a+b{{\cos }^{2}}\left( x \right)}dx}$$
I don't think a substitution is an option here, besides differentiation under the sign integral makes the integral harder. Fortunately Mathematica gives a closed form for the integral in question:

$$\frac{\pi \tan^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} \right)}{\sqrt{ab}}$$

Comment: You can replace $x$ with $\pi - x$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

Enforce the substitution $x\mapsto \pi-x$.

Then, note that

$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{x\sin(x)}{a+b\cos^2(x)}\,dx=\int_0^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)\sin(x)}{a+b\cos^2(x)}\,dx$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: that was quick and simple and i can finish the rest of the solution using the Tangent half-angle substitution?

Comment: @logo It'd be easier to use $u=\cos x$.

Comment: you are right, thanks

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I & \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi}{x\sin\pars{x} \over a + b\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\pars{x + \pi/2}\cos\pars{x} \over a + b\sin^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{x} \over a + b\sin^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\pi\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over bx^{2} + a}
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\,{1 \over a}\,\root{a \over b}\int_{0}^{1}{\root{b/a}\dd x \over  \pars{\root{b/a}x}^{2} + 1} =
{\pi \over \root{ab}}\int_{0}^{\root{b/a}}{\dd x \over  x^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\pi \over \root{ab}}\,\arctan\pars{\root{b \over a}}}
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) Hello Felix, my friend!

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks, Mark. Hello.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts:

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{a + b \cos^2x} \, dx = \boxed{\frac \pi{\sqrt{ab}} \arctan\sqrt{\frac ba}} + \frac1{\sqrt{ab}} \int_0^\pi \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac ba} \cos x\right) \, dx$$

The remaining integral vanishes thanks to symmetry about $x=\dfrac\pi2$:

$$\int_0^\pi \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac ba} \cos x\right) \, dx \stackrel{x\mapsto\pi-x}= -\int_0^\pi \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac ba} \cos x\right) \, dx$$